# How to redirect output to several files with bash, without forking?

Tags: bash, shell

I run my_program via a bash wrapper script, and use exec to prevent forking a separate process:

```
  #! /bin/bash
  exec my_program >> /tmp/out.log 2>&1
```

Now I would like to duplicate all output into two different files, **but still prevent forking**, so I do **not** want to use a pipe and tee like this:

```
  #! /bin/bash
  exec my_program 2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/out.log >> /tmp/out2.log
```

**How to do that with bash?**

The reasons for avoid forking is to make sure that:

1. all signals sent to the bash script also reaches my_program (including non-trappable signals).
2. waitpid(3) on the bash-script can never return before my_program has also terminated.

Comment: Note that some versions of `tee` can accept more than one file argument (e.g. `... | tee file1 file2 file3`). I'm not sure this can be done without either using `tee` or at least forking subshells...

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is to redirect standard output and error to `tee` via a process substitution:

```
exec > >( tee -a /tmp/out.log >> /tmp/out2.log) 2>&1
```

then `exec` to replace the `bash` script with your program (which will keep the same open file handles to standard output).

```
exec my_program
```

Comment: There's obviously an implicit fork here as well, though. I don't think this can be accomplished without one.

Comment: In his attempt, the `exec` doesn't really replace the current shell script; it replaces the shell that is forked by the pipe. Here, the call to `tee` is farmed out to a child process rather than a "sibling" process; the parent is truly replaced by `exec my_program`, so I think it satisfies the two requirements.

Comment: Interesting, it might work for my situation. Would all output from my_program be visible in the output files, at the moment when waitpid(3) on the bash-script returns? If not, how can I wait until all output is visible?

Comment: Technically, `waitpid` is not waiting on the bash script; it's waiting on the process which used to be executing the bash script, but is now executing `my_program`. That detail aside, I believe that `tee` should be terminated once the file handle it reads from is closed by the termination of `my_program`, and `tee` should close the log files before ending.